# Google AdSense in AngularJS partials - Why does changing views display ads in the wrong sizes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, asynchronous, adsense

I have an AngularJS application in production approved by Google AdSense.  This application updates an `ng-view` element with partial templates from a few different link clicks.  I am using two different ad sizes one box and another leaderboard.

The ads seem to display appropriately on initial page load but upon changing the view the following happens:

[image: square ad in banner shaped iframe]
[image: leaderboard ad in square ad container]

Adsense is loading a square ad into the iframe sized/shaped for a leaderboard, and the result is a nasty 'clipping' of the ad content.  This effect also happens in reverse, leaderboard ads load into square sized iframes with a similar clipping effect.

I am utilizing the standard `ng-directive` approach the internet seems to deem the norm for populating divs with google adsense content. please find the javascript here:

```
app.directive('myAdSense', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {}
    }
});
```

and one html example from template partials here:

```
<div data-my-ad-sense>
    <!-- Display Partial Leaderboard -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px;float:right;"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-11111111111"
        data-ad-slot="11111111"></ins>
    <script>
        try{
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        }catch(ex){}
    </script>
</div>
```

When accessing any particular view directly (with routing) the ads all appear fine, but after clicking through the application this improper ad sizing is a nearly 100% occurrence.  I've searched google, the adsense help forum and adsense faq without finding the cause or solution.

### Why does changing views display ads in the wrong sizes? How can I stop this sizing phenomenon?

thanks in advance - sorry for the wall of text

Comment: Can you please create a plunker?

Comment: tried to create a plunker but was unable to get my ads to appear outside of my domain, looking for a "sandbox" or test publisher id for async example to get that up and running for you

Comment: i experience something similar:
I have 4 ads in a view. i change view. When i come back my ads are gone (or just 1-2-3 of them......randomly.)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it looks very much like there is some inconsistency in the build sequence of your included views. This seems even more likely when considering your statement, that the error occurs *almost* every time you do a route change from within your app.

I'm not very experienced with the inner workings of the AdSense SDK, but I'd try to execute the `try .. catch` statement (or whatever initial call is necessary to set up a ad container) in the body of your link function, because the link function call in AngularJS reliably happens only after everything has been compiled and added to the DOM. 
I'd generally have *all* scripted logic in my directives, especially when we're talking `ng-view` partials.

On top of that, I'd further investigate the possibilities of asynchronously initialising single ad containers (https://developers.google.com/adsense/).

This may sound a little like fishing in muddy waters to you, but that's what I'd do anyways.

Comment: thanks for the reply, experimented with adding the `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` lines to the link function without any success. following up with further adsense api ill keep you posted

Comment: unfortunately not - ive thrown maybe 8 hours into alternative solutions and research with no luck, its dropped in priorities but once i clear off the todo list im going to give it a second shot

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution @Joe ...news?

Comment: unfortunately been busy and this issue has dropped down in importance for me... i have looked into it but with no further success